# WPF Xaml Designer is getting Out Of Memory due to Embedded Resources in the ModelVIew

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xaml-designer

So I had this problem for a while, and the only way to go around is to change the build action of the embedded resources to none then build the MV. After that, I build the View and it works like a charm. However If the resources build action is embedded, the View build with no problem, but the designer Xaml throws out of memory exception and does not load. Has anyone experienced these issues? Any real fix, besides changing the build action of the resources to none?

Comment: witch kind of resources ?

Comment: project resource file

Comment: Ok, I made you an answer already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the "Build Action" to "Content".

Indeed, if you set Build Action to resources, it will be embedded resource in an assembly, but if you set Build Action to content then it will be provided in the resulting file .xap, in this cas you can get you resource like: "/Resources/myResource.xyz".

hope it helps